# Spline 3D Scene isn't rendering properly in React SPA, throwing bunch of repeated errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React application using Three.js and React Three Fiber. I'm trying to implement OrbitControls for my 3D scene, but I keep encountering the following error: "Cannot access 'OrbitControls' before initialization". I've tried changing the way i import some modules, how i declare the canvas + contained elements and several solutions from online resources but nothing seems to work.
I've installed the three-stdlib package and imported the OrbitControls from it, and created a custom OrbitControls component using useThree and useEffect hooks to instantiate the OrbitControls class. However, when I try to render the OrbitControls component in the Canvas component, I get the following error: "target is not a constructor".

Here's my current code

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, Suspense } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls as StdlibOrbitControls } from 'three-stdlib';
import { Canvas, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { Application } from '@splinetool/runtime';
import { ReactComponent as LogoC } from './images/logo-c.svg';
import { ReactComponent as MenuButton } from './images/menu-button.svg';
import { ReactComponent as RArrow } from './images/right-arrow-desktop.svg';

const SplineScene = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const app = new Application(canvas);
    app.load('https://prod.spline.design/dulgIWpUS02bwIc2/scene.splinecode');

    return () => {
      app.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />;
};

const Loading = () => {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
};

function OrbitControls() {
    const { camera, gl } = useThree();
    const controls = useRef();
  
    useEffect(() => {
      controls.current = new StdlibOrbitControls(camera, gl.domElement);
      return () => controls.current.dispose();
    }, [camera, gl.domElement]);
  
    return null;
  };

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <section className='fullPage'>
        <nav className='navigation'>
            <div className='logo'>
            <LogoC />
            </div>
            <div className='menu-button'>
            <MenuButton />
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div className='home'>
            <div className='heading-1'>
            <span>Curious huh?</span>
            <span>Us too.</span>
            </div>
        <div className='3d-image'>
            <Canvas concurrent shadowMap>
            <ambientLight />
            <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
            <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                <SplineScene />
            </Suspense>
            <OrbitControls />
            </Canvas>
        </div>
        <div className='heading-2'>
                <span>We're launching</span>
                <div>
                    <span className='soon'>soon</span>
                    <div className='newsletter'>
                        <input className='newsletter-email-input' placeholder='your email goes here'></input>
                        <button className='newsletter-submit-button'>Let me know</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer className='contact'>
            <div className='section-title'>
                <span>Get in touch</span>
                <span>
                <RArrow />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className='social-links'>
                <a href="https://www.twitter.com/xxxxxxx" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Twitter</a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/xxxxxxx" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Instagram</a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/xxxxxxxxx" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">LinkedIn</a>
                <a href="mailto:hello@xxxxxxxx.co" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Email</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

--Errors--

```
target is not a constructor
TypeError: target is not a constructor
```

```
R3F: Canvas is not part of the THREE namespace! Did you forget to extend? See: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/objects#using-3rd-party-objects-declaratively
```